# enable systemd service in non-default target like `chkconfig --level` did

Tags: centos, systemd

In Centos 6 I used:

```
chkconfig --level 12345 network on
chkconfig --level 12345 sshd on
```

Now have Centos 7.1. Is it possible to additionally enable `sshd` in `resque.target` using some command line tool? Or should I manually create the symlinks?

Upd: tried the manual way. I didn't help: the server was inaccessible by ssh

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/rescue.target.wants
ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service /etc/systemd/system/rescue.target.wants/
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl isolate rescue.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the ultimate (so far) set of commands:

```
chkconfig --level 12345 network on
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants
ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/
ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/
systemctl daemon-reload
```

I use `network-online` instead of `rescue`, because there are other targets like `emergency`.

`chkconfig` is also needed, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to do this would be to edit the service definition file, and add a `WantedBy` entry for the target you want.  So you could edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` and add `WantedBy=rescue.target` as another line in the `[Install]` section, then do `systemctl enable sshd` and it should create the links you want.

You could also add `rescue.target` to the existing `WantedBy` line by adding it after a space after any existing values.

Of course, if sshd is part of the problem you really might not want it to try autostarting in rescue mode. . .

Comment: This advice seems dubious just from looking at the recommendation to edit package-managed files. But googling `rescue.target.wants` really doesn't provide anything, it's like nobody is interested in augmenting it with networking. I'm about to try some things out here and will later post learnings if I find any.